# Where to find coordinates of geographic centers of US counties?

Tags: data, gps, united-states

Where can I find a list of the latitude/longitude coordinates of the geographic centers (centroids) of each US county?

Comment: Not sure about an existing list, but why not get a layer of US counties and take the centroids and convert them to lat/long and create your own??

Comment: I doubt you will find such a confirmed list. The two answers thus far rely on obtaining polygon data from a source and using it to calculate centroids. Their accuracy is going to depend on the mapping source/method/accuracy that went in to creating them. If you're looking for confirmed coordinates, it would have to be done from survey level/grade data. And it depends on what datum you're using. So what are you looking for - just centroid coordinates as the answers give, or actual confirmed GPS coordinates in a particular CRS/datum?

Comment: Combining the answers from [DenaliHardtail](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/136034/25830) and [Fatemeh Asgarinejad](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/344147/25830) below currently turns up the [US Census Gazetteer page](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/geo/gazetteer-files.html) whose National Counties Gazetteer File would seems to have the definitive answer to the question (which seems pretty focused to me.)

Answer (score 3):

If you have ArcGIS Desktop, you can follow the directions below and it will take about 5 minutes.

1. Download [US Counties from ESRI](https://geonet.esri.com/servlet/JiveServlet/download/183957-26877/UScounties.zip)
2. Follow ESRI's instruction at [HowTo: Find the centroid of polygons using Calculate Geometry](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/32988)
3. This results in a table of Latitude and Longitude attributes as well as points for the centers on your map.

[image]

[image]

Comment: You can download a comma delimited text file of the table above here: https://drive.bitcasa.com/send/2GZDyS6RPVAmPP2KiHeG3AZCPKWH5t2HN0p0KExsJEFB

Answer (score 3):

I found this wikipedia page very helpful:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User:Michael_J/County_table
It shows a list of all us counties with their center coordinates (and a lot more information).

Answer (score 1):

The county features in the geodatabases found [here](http://www.census.gov/geo/maps-data/data/tiger-geodatabases.html) contain two columns (INTPTLAT and INTPTLON) that represent the centroid of the county. I used several state geodatabases but have not attempted to verify the accuracy of the centroids listed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use the data which is provided by United States government in [here](https://www.census.gov/geographies/reference-files/time-series/geo/gazetteer-files.html).

Although for using it you need to clean it first. Some counties names are not correctly written as they consist of non-English alphabets.

Answer (score 0):

Use Google Geocoding API: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro

Search ",  county"

This returns the lat / long of the geographic center from what I can tell.

Comment: note that they longitude contains a long dash "–" instead of a negative sign "-".  Also looks like a typo for at least one location in Alaska